# Why is the regex to match 1 to 10 written as [1-9]|10 and not [1-10]?

Tags: regex

Why is the regex to match numbers from 1 to 10 commonly written as follows?

```
[1-9]|10
```

Instead of:

```
[1-10]
```

Or this:

```
[1-(10)]
```

Comment: It's about a *character* range and not a *number* range. Basically you read it as a number, but regex reads it as a mere character.

Comment: `[1-10]` would match a `1` or a `0` and nothing else.

Comment: Fyi, `[1-9]|10` could also be written as `10?|[2-9]`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Sometime a good drawing worth 1000 words...*

Here are the three propositions in your question and the way a regex flavour would understand them:

### [1-9]|10

[image: Regular expression image]

### [1-10]

[image: Regular expression image]

### [1-(10)]

```
Invalid regexp !!
```

This regex is invalid because a range is opened (`1-`) with a digit but not closed with another digit (ends with `(`).

A range is usually bound with digits on both sides or letters on both sides.

*Images generated with [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)*

Comment: Thanks, awesome — why is the last one invalid? Brackets seem to work well in Google Analytics regex

Comment: I know this is 4 years old but correcting some information: `10|[1-9]` has higher likely hood of succeeding some versions of regex assess the OR statements in order and will match the first correct result, so the value `10` might only capture the `1` of the `10` not the whole number.

Comment: @Stephan also, the range in the last regex isn't invalid because the second character isn't a digit, it's because the ASCII / unicode index of `(` is lower than that of `1`, and you can't specify ranges in decreasing order of indices.

Comment: @Stephen how did you create those pictures? did you do it manually or with a tool?

Answer (score 19):

That is because regexes work with characters, not with numbers. `[1-9]` is equivalent to `(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)` while `[1-10]` would be `(?:1|0)` (because it's the range 1–1 and the digit 0).

Simply put, ranges in character classes always refer to contiguous ranges of characters, despite how they look. Even if they're digits that doesn't mean there is any kind of numeric range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you have a moment, could you also clarify why `[1-(10)]` wouldn't work?

Comment: Because regex doesn't recognize numbers, it recognizes digits and characters. So even though we as humans recognize that 10 is the number after 9, regex has no concept of that; all it know about are the digits from 0-9. As such, '10' isn't a number in regex, it's a digit sequence comprising of two digits 1 and 0.

Comment: @Baumr: Because that would still only consider the individual characters and thus would try (and fail) to generate a character range from `1-(`.

Answer (score 10):

```
[1-9]|10
```

In this:

- `[1-9]` accepts any *character* from 1 through 9;
- `|` performs an "or" operation;
- `10` accepts the 10 literally.

```
[1-10]
```

This accepts:

- any single character between 1 and 1,
- or `0`.

Comment: This was very messy. Now it's not.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo ;)

Answer (score 3):

No matter what pattern is inside `[...]` (character class), it only matches a *single* character.

The way the range operator (`-`) inside character class works is it takes a single character as left operand, and a single character as right operand, then expand it to a list of characters.

So, looking at the ranges in your examples

- `1-9` (1 to 9) in `[1-9]|10` (equivalent to `[123456789]|10`)
- `1-1` (1 to 1) in `[1-10]` (equivalent to `[10]` which is the same as `[01]`)
- `1-(` (1 to opening parenthesis) in `[1-(10)]`

  - I actually get an error with this in Perl because the range `1` to `(` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is about the character matching. When you say `[1-9]` it means it matches any individual characters from 1 to 9. Number 10 would be treated as 2 separate characters.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `[]` symbols represent character set, e.g. `[0-5]` matchers 0-5. However, 10 has two digits and therefore `[0-9]` will not produce an exact match (will only match the first digit, '1' of '10'.

The pipe symbol `|` can be seen as a "or" operator.

Comment: It's more like an "or" operator. "and" implies you must match both at the same time, which can't really happen.

Answer (score 0):

That's the basic definition of a character class. `[1-10]` means "match any character in the range 1 though 1, or 0". Character classes are evaluated character by character (except for escape sequences and `-`); they don't understand numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` indicates a single character match

for example `[ab]` would match either `a` or `b`

so `[1-9]` which is effectively shorthand for `[123456789]` would match a single character that is one of the digits from `1` to `9`

Your example of `[1-10]` would expand the 1-1 to mean all characters in the range `1` to `1` (i.e `1`) so the actual regex would expand to be [10] (i.e. either the character 1 or the character 0)

Answer (score -4):

```
\[([1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\]
```

This will remove Wikipedia's references when you copy something for your project.