# java split regex - any combination of characters

Tags: java, regex

I am splitting a string using 3 characters: space, dash and comma

What I want is to be able to split using any combination of these 3 characters for example:

`-,` (dash followed by comma) or `,--` (comma followed by 2 dash) or `- , -` (dash space comma space dash) etc

```
    String address = "Sector -18B, Dwarka";
    String[] addressParts = address.split("[\\s+,-]");
    for (String part : addressParts) 
       System.out.println(part + " - " + part.isEmpty());
```

This gives me a 5 length array: ["Sector", "", "18B", "", "Dwarka"]

I want a 3 length array: ["Sector", "18B", "Dwarka"]

How should I write the regular expression?

Comment: `[\\s,-]+` would do the job

Comment: @HamZa - put as an answer and take the rep ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba if I did that, I should have put [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341103/why-is-the-regex-to-match-1-to-10-written-as-1-910-and-not-1-10#comment25158238_17341103) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345827/list-of-all-php-preg-replace-characters-to-escape#comment25166973_17345827) as answers :)

Comment: @Hamza - I'd like to suggest a 'Dignified' badge for your kind of behaviour; at Gold level of course. How could I do that?

Comment: @Bathsheba Post a suggestion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but I'm not sure if they would accept it. But you can always try :)

Comment: @HamZa: dunnit, citing this question as an example.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `"(\\s|,|-)+"` as the regex pattern

```
String address = "Sector -18B, Dwarka";
String[] addressParts = address.split("(\\s|,|-)+");
for (String part : addressParts) 
    System.out.println(part + " - " + part.isEmpty());
```

Output:

```
Sector - false
18B - false
Dwarka - false
```

Comment: In a character class, `|` is considered as a literal `|` which means that it doesn't mean "or", it will actually match `|`. So you have another option: use `(\\s|,|-)+`

Comment: I agree.. Thanks for pointing it out we should use parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

```
String address = "Sector -18B, Dwarka";
String[] addressParts = address.split("[\\s,-]+");
for (String part : addressParts){ 
System.out.println(part + " - " + part.isEmpty());
}
```