# regular expression to accept only numbers within specific range

Tags: c#, regex

I was trying regular expression 
to accept only numbers and it should not allow to accept more than ten

```
^[]0,10]{0,10}$
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: `^[0-9]{0,10}$` will match 0 to 10 any digits. `^(?:[0-9]|10)$` will accept 1-10 range of numbers. What are you exactly after?

Comment: Omit the clsing bracket at the beginning. This will probably solve this issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some examples ... You question is unclear now ..!

Comment: Just in case: [Why is the regex to match 1 to 10 written as \[1-9\]|10 and not \[1-10\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341103/why-is-the-regex-to-match-1-to-10-written-as-1-910-and-not-1-10)

Answer (score 1):

This matches just this range of numbers: `[0-9]`

```
^([0-9])$
```

And then you can use `$1` if you need to replace is with something else ...

Or also you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` like this:

```
^(\d)$
```

And if you want to accept `10`, you have to use `|`. Some thing like this;

```
^(\d|10)$
```

As I said, this ^ regex accept both this range `[0-9]` and `10`.

Comment: There is no point in answering a question if the question is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed ... I flagged it ..!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
^[0-9]{0,10}$
```

Comment: Why should anyone try that? OP iis looking for a regex to *accept only numbers within specific range*.

Comment: I don't see your point. I think, this is a possible answer to the question above.

Comment: There is no point in answering a question if the question is unclear.

Comment: I think this regex is wrong ..., As far as I understood what OP mentioned, regex has to accept just *one-digit* ..! `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `9`. Just that. But your regex matches ten-digit https://regex101.com/r/eC2oC4/1

Comment: @Shafizadeh: any answer for an unclear question is right and wrong at the same time. Thus, makes no sense at all.